How do I clone from local git repositories with ssh?
The final goal is to host a remote repo on my pc that support pushing and pulling.
From the official doc given by git help clone, the host url format should be
git clone ssh://user@localhost:/C:/path/to/repo
or
git clone git://localhost:/C:/path/to/repo
Git clone ssh returned
fatal: ''/C:/path/to/repo'' does not appear to be a git repository
While git clone git returned
fatal: unable to connect to localhost:
localhost[0: ::1]: errno=Unknown error
localhost[1: 127.0.0.1]: errno=Unknown error

The repo is default repo without the --bare flag, but i think that should not affect cloning but pushing to master right?
The repo have existing commits
Ive tried localhost/C/ (without :) and path/to/repo.git but to no luck
I saw guides that suggests git@localhost but that doesnt make any sense, i supposed they forgot to mention its for github and gitlab or sth, so i didnt paid much attention to that
For my ssh setup, i have a ed25519 and rsa 4096 bit key pairs, with private key registered to my identity with ssh-add and public key copied to authorized_keys under ~/.ssh/ (and restarted) sshd
ssh user@localhost will bring me into the ssh shell as expected
The sshd_config file was not modified much, but for the sake of troubleshooting i reset it to sshd_config_default
The permissions are also fine, checked with the perm fix scripts which came along with the windows openssh package
Path is configured correctly for the custom openssh ssh file instead of the window's one
cloning from github with pubkey auth work fine
so i assume its a problem in the host side
And GIT_SSH=/path/to/ssh.exe, GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh
oh and scp works perfectly fineon directories
I might be missing something in the docs, is there anything else that need to be configured before ssh clone can be used? Thanks
Windows 11 Pro 23H2
OpenSSH_for_Windows_9.5p1, LibreSSL 3.8.2
git version 2.45.0.windows.1

To start with, you're mixing two different address formats here. Git supports URL format addresses and rsh/rcp-format addresses, but what you're trying to use has a mix of features from both.

rcp-format addresses (or scp-format; rcp being the ancient predecessor of SSH's scp) use a colon : as the separator between host and path, and they do not have the "URL scheme" prefix:
user@host:path
user@host:/path


URL-format addresses always use slash /-separated components, just like in http://, and do not have a : in between (unless to specify a port number).
ssh://user@host/path
git://host/path
git://host:port/path
http://user@host/path



So you need to use either ssh://user@localhost/C:/foo or user@localhost:C:/foo. (Not git:// – that's for the read-only, clear-text "git-daemon" connections.)
That aside, the real problem is with the server configuration. Git over SSH works by invoking "git-upload-pack <path>" as the remote command (so that it could talk the Git protocol over SSH), but it does so by using the sh/bash syntax to quote the repository path using 'single quotes'. For example, it sends:
git-upload-pack 'C:/path/to/repo'

which is not understood by the Cmd.exe shell on the server side (nor does Git for Windows have any special handling for it on its own), and as a result git-upload-pack thinks that the repository path is literally 'C:/path/to/repo' with the single-quotes included.
A workaround for this – one that I've used way back on Windows XP – would be to create a custom wrapper script on the server that will get invoked instead of the real git-upload-pack.exe, and which takes care of the un-quoting (either by manual string operations or by invoking actual sh). In my backups from the old PC, I have:

C:\Users\xxxxx\git-upload-pack.cmd
@"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh" -c "'/c/Program Files/Git/bin/git' upload-pack %*"

Place the .cmd batch script anywhere that would be found by Cmd as a command – e.g. in C:\Windows or in your user's home directory, or in any custom place that's listed in your PATH – so that it would be found before the .exe in "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd".
Repeat this for git-receive-pack to make 'git push' work.

(In addition to that, if you use the URI syntax (ssh://, as opposed to the rcp syntax) then it also includes a leading slash / as part of the path, e.g. /C:/test.git, but fortunately that is understood by Git for Windows due to it being a MinGW-based program, so it doesn't become a problem.)
